# Texture2D to front

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d

Is there any option to set the mouse texture to the front of the screen?

The mouse pointer and the blocks are `Texture2D`s, is it possible to draw the pointer in front of the other textures?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `SpriteBatch.Draw()` overload that allows you to set the layer depth. setting it to 0 places the texture in front and setting it to 1 places it in the back. But it only applies within a Begin/end block.

Most likely, you can achieve what you want by simply drawing it last and it will go on top(or front) of all other drawn items.

Comment: Thank you found that and it worked for me
i had to put the mouse after the map in the draw thank you